# I have to make new module in magento 2 but pub/static are changed

Tags: module, magento2.1.6

I have to make new module, I took backup from server to local and after executing commend "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" layout and function not working properly, It seem like someone worked in pub/static folder files.

Now i complete my module in localhost and need to upload at server, Did any way to upload module and run without "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" commend ?

My module also have database table.

Can you please advise me the best way.

Comment: Yeah needs to run on each database to enable the module and update tables if required.

Comment: which tables I have to update to enable my module? I am new Magento Developer. 
1)
app/etc/config.php (SampleModule' => 1)
2) 
Setup_modules (database table)
3)
Make my module database table

What else I have to update to enable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Magento2, It is best way to run `"php bin/magento setup:upgrade"` command followed by below commands,

```
rm -rf pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/adminhtml pub/static/frontend
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
rm -rf var/cache var/page_cache var/generation 
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/
```

In you local you can set

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

If still issues persist, share your log.

Comment: Thanks @pallvi, As I told, I run this command, but in my project its already someone worked in pub/static folder. 
Its mean that pub/static files are updated one and app/code, app/designs are not updated files.

Comment: you need to tell your project manager for this issue as pub/static files are cached files and should be generated automatically. If this is not happening then there will be no development possible with standard coding.
If possible create a backup folder for pub/static and then remove its content and deploy. Hope that helps!